# When validation rules is set in parent show error message in child component in livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

Tried everything but got no success.
Setting required rules in the parent component and listening in the child. But it doesn't show any error message on real-time update. Below is the code
Remember the rule is set in parent component and below code is of the child component.

PARENT COMPONENT

```
public function rules() {
        return [
            'category_ids' => ['required'],
        ];
    }
protected $listeners = ['selectedCategory'];

    public function selectedCategory($selectedId)
    {
        $this->category_ids= $selectedId;
    }

<!-----parent component blade----->

<div class="form_input_wrapper mb-3">
     @livewire('fetch-category', ['category_ids' => $category_ids])
</div>
```

CHILD COMPONENT

```
public function updatedCategoryIds($data)
{
    $this->emitUp('selectedCategory',$data);
}

<!-------child component blade-------->

<div class="form-group col-md-6" wire:ignore>
    <label class="col-form-label">Category</label>
        <select class="form-control kt-selectpicker" multiple data-actions-box="true" wire:model="category_ids" wire:change="$emit('updatedCategoryIds',{{ collect($category_ids) }})">
             @foreach($this->categories as $id=> $cat)
               <option value="{{ $id }}">{!! $cat !!}</option>
             @endforeach
        </select>
        @error('category_ids') <div class="invalid-feedback">{{$message}}</div>@enderror
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The components aren't inheriting any data or state, even if they are parent-children. So validation doesn't apply from parents to child components either. As an alternative solution, you could:

- move the validation into the child and trigger it via an event in the parent and a listener in the child
- push the data via events into the component and run the validation on setting the values.

Comment: Would like to push data via events to child because child component which I am using is dynamic which can be used anywhere. So that means rules can be different for each.
Pushing data via events ? Could you elaborate more ?

Comment: Sure, you emit an event `$this->emit('event-name', $data)` containing your data. On the "other end", you receive the data, can trigger the update with it the validation. This should cover it mostly: https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/events

Comment: But as you can see I am already emitting an event in the child component on change so I am getting the updated value in parent. What else is left ?

Comment: Do you listen to the event in the child component? Can you share all relevant code (parent component+child, each with livewire component and blade file)?

Comment: Yeah, sure. I have updated the question. As I said emitting event in child and listening in the parent so that the parent component could have updated value.

Comment: From the looks you want to do the validation directly in the child component (maybe both). I would copy the validation down or pass the validation array as an argument while mounting.

Comment: Did you mean mount error in child component?

Comment: Add an array or method for the rules to the child component. As shown here: https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/input-validation

Comment: Doesn't work on submitting as submit button is present in the parent component

Comment: What I have managed to do is I am resetting and adding validation on the basis of value in the listener which is present in the parent.

Comment: Instead of using a classical submit you need to trigger validation in the child component instead, wait for the response and process the submit. You can do it with events: sending one to start the validation and one after. It's getting increasingly complex with this, but that's the only approach I've found working.

Comment: Ok I will try that too and will let you know.